# Copy Excel content and send it using Outlook

Tags: blueprism, rpa

So I want to copy few rows and column from an Excel file and mail that copied content using Outlook. The important thing is that my Excel contains color and different fonts and i want the same theme/design in my mail.
New to BluePrism, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to solve this, the simplest one (albeit not very robust) would be using the `Copy` function from `MS Excel VBO` and then do a Paste Special on the Outlook Message.

[image]

Then select whichever format you prefer.

- HTML format will be smallest, but may not 100% capture the Excel look
- Bitmap will be largest, but will 100% capture the Excel look
- Picture should be like the bitmap, but I have noticed some minor differences

[image]

Make sure you have the mail body activated when you are doing the paste, so you are not attempting to paste the contents into the address list.